# Get li background colors and apply it to another list

Tags: jquery, html, css, list

I have two identical lists.

One has each li with a specific color, the other does not.

I am trying to get each li background color and add each color to each li.

I am making a mistake (shown in codepen), currently the last li color is being added to all li items on the second list.

[See my codepen.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LEQERq)

```
<ul id="toCopy">
 <li class="red">List Item</ll>
 <li class="green">List Item</ll>
 <li class="blue">List Item</ll>
</ul>

<ul id="copyTo">
 <li>List Item</ll>
 <li>List Item</ll>
 <li>List Item</ll>
</ul> 


$('#toCopy').each(function () {
 $('li', this).each(function () {
  bgcolor = $(this).css('backgroundColor');
  var arr = jQuery.makeArray( bgcolor );

    for(var i=0; i< arr.length; i++) {
     $('#copyTo li').each(function () {
       $(this).css("background-color",arr[i]);
     })
    }

    })
})
```

Where am I going wrong with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're targeting all elements in the second list, you could probably target by using the index instead

```
$('#toCopy li').each(function () {
    var bgcolor = $(this).css('backgroundColor');

    $('#copyTo li').eq( $(this).index() ).css('backgroundColor', bgcolor);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/dchc7ny0/3/)

You could even reverse that and do

```
$('#copyTo li').css('backgroundColor', function() {
    return $('#toCopy li').eq($(this).index()).css('backgroundColor');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/dchc7ny0/2/)

Note that you have typos in the all the closing tags, it's not `</ll>` but `</li>`